# Pandas Mean Issue

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the mean of rows in a pandas df. The result seems to be wrong

```
    print(df)
    df_temp = df.drop([str(dt.today().year)],axis=1)   
    print(df_temp)        
    df['mean'] = df_temp.mean(axis=1,skipna=False)
    print(df)
```

[image]

Edit: Strange! when I recreate the df I get the right answer:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'2017':111764,'2018':36606,'2019':62221,'2020':43472,'2021':42606,'2022':32864}])      
print(df)      
df_temp = df.drop([str(dt.today().year)], axis=1)      
print(df_temp)
df['mean'] = df_temp.mean(axis=1, skipna=False)   

print(df)


     2017   2018   2019   2020   2021   2022     mean
0  111764  36606  62221  43472  42606  32864  59333.8
```

Answer (score 0):

df.astype(float) fixed the issue